# pyhash module can't be installed with pip

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install the module pyhash using the following command :

pip install pyhash

however, I'm getting the following :

```py
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ver\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\VER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a6et1ql6\\pyhash\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\VER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a6et1ql6\\pyhash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6et1ql6\pyhash\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6et1ql6\pyhash\setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        os.path.join(os.environ.get('PYTHON_HOME'), 'include'),
      File "c:\users\ver\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\ntpath.py", line 76, in join
        path = os.fspath(path)
    TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it from Pypi from their it will get installed.